# How to properly use Fire&Forget in Async Environment

Tags: c#, asynchronous, fire-and-forget

Consider the following:

```
//base stuff
private readonly ConcurrentQueue<message> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<message>();
private readonly MyCacheData _cache  = new MyCacheData ();
//setuo
timer = new Timer { Interval = 60_000, AutoReset = true };
timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60); // 60 seconds too
//

// each 60 seconds
private async void OnTimedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
   if (cache 30 minutes old)
   { 
      //Fire and Forget GetWebDataAsync()
      // and continue executing next stuff
      // if I await it will wait 60 seconds worst case
      // until going to the queue and by this time another 
      // timed even fires
   }

   // this always should execute each 60 seconds
   if (queue isnt empty)
   {
       process queue
   }
}

// heavy cache update each 10-30 minutes
private async Task GetWebDataAsync()
{
   if (Semaphore.WaitAsync(1000))
   {
      try
      {
            //fetch WebData update cache
            //populate Queue if needed
      }
      catch (Exception)
      {
      }
      finally
      {
          release Semaphore
      }
   }
}
```

Colored: https://ghostbin.com/paste/6edov

Because I cheat and use the cheap ConcurrentQueue solution I don't really care much about what happens during GetWebDataAsync(), I just want to fire it and do its job, while I instantly go to process queue because it always must be done each 60 seconds or timer resolution.

How do I correctly do that, avoid much overhead or unnecessary thread spawning?

**EDIT:** got an answer for my case elsewhere

```
private async void OnTimedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    async void DoGetWebData() => await GetWebDataAsync()

    if (condition)
    { 
        DoGetWebData(); // Fire&Forget and continue, exceptions handled inside
    }

        //no (a)waiting for the GetWebDataAsync(), we already here
    if (queue isnt empty)
    {
        //process queue
    }

}


private async Task GetWebDataAsync()
{
    if (Semaphore.WaitAsync(1000))
    {
        try
        {
        //fetch WebData update cache
        //populate Queue if needed
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //log stuff
        }
        finally
        {
            ///always release lock
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Task.Run(...);
ThreadPool.QueueUserItem(...);
```

Anything wrong with these?...

How about something like that:

```
    ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    void Foo()
    {
        new Thread(() => 
        {
            while (mre.WaitOne())
            {
                /*process queue item*/
                if (/*queue is empty*/)
                {
                    mre.Reset();
                }
            }
        }) { IsBackground = true }.Start();
    }

    void AddItem()
    {
        /*queue add item*/
        mre.Set();
    }
```

Comment: So `Task.Rum => Mymethod` is a proper way to go? I cant answer your question because it is part of my own question I'm asking haha\

Comment: Will do the job, sure. It has several overloads to start a task; you don't have to use the returned value. It is not easy to tell what "the right way" is. I could also imagine having one dedicated writer thread monitoring a queue while others just put items into it... or about one million other designs/implementations.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the tips Jaster, got an answer elsewhere as well and updated my post!

Answer (score 0):

Call an `async` method from another `async` method **without** `await` statement

Comment: Yes, but I will get the SQUIGGLES man, IDE code analysis will be very disappointed in me, telling that there is clearly a more proper way to do it I don't know. My point is I'm asking for proper practices/usage. i can do it brainlet way, since that's the best I'm capable of :P

Comment: You could do async void, no?

If you're doing Task as a return type, and the method throws an exception, that exception is only thrown when Task is awaited.  If you never await it, the exception is silent, which is the main reason for that warning.

Either make it void, or await it I'd say.